# many facebook feed dialogs on the same page: only the last uploaded picture is shared

Tags: jquery, facebook, bind, feed

I have a form with many pictures to upload and one share on facebook button for each picture.

If I upload and share one picture on Facebook, it works. However, if I upload two pictures and try to share the first one, it's the second one that is shared in facebook!

index.html:

```
<!-- html code for each picture to upload -->
<div class="show_hide"> 

    <div class="div_question_photo">
        <div class="div_upload_question_photo">Take a photo</div>
    </div>

    <div class="share_buttons">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center facebook_buttons">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-facebook facebook_share_button">
                 <span class="fb-icon"></span><span class="fb-text">Share on Facebook</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

index.js

```
//for each photo question, add an ajax uploader to upload the picture
$('.div_question_photo').each(function()
{   
    var input=$(this).find("input");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', input[0].files[0]);

    input.fileupload(
    {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "{% url 'campaigns:upload_question_photo' %}",
        formData: formData,

        progress: function (e, data) 
        {                        
            $(this).closest(".show_hide").find(".percentage").html(" (" + percentage + "%)");
        }.bind(this),

        //the file has been successfully uploaded
        done: function (e, data) 
        {
            response=data.result;

            show_hide=$(this).closest(".show_hide"); 
            share_div=show_hide.find(".share_buttons");
            facebook_share_button=share_div.find(".facebook_share_button");
            facebook_share_button.click(function(event)
            {
                //don't send form
                event.preventDefault();

                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Share photo',
                    link: response.link,
                    picture: response.path,
                },
                function(response) 
                {
                    ...   
                }
                );

            });

        }.bind(this),

        processfail: function (e, data) 
        {
            $(this).closest(".show_hide").find(".status_photo_question").html("failed");
        }.bind(this)
    });

});
```

Is the problem related to the bind?

Answer (score 0):

here is the problematic code:

```
facebook_share_button=share_div.find(".facebook_share_button");
```

you are re-binding to all buttons with the classname **facebook_share_button**. You should scope the buttons instead of this code block. I couldn't see how you append the share buttons tho.

you should add share buttons whenever your ajax completed and then bind the related data to that button instead of finding all buttons with the same classname.

Comment: I have edited my code with `show_hide=$(this).closest(".show_hide")` so now `facebook_share_button` should be binded to only one element, right?